# Why would a Post from Postman to MVC6 webapp running under localhost work, but not to the same app deployed on IIS10 server

Tags: postman, asp.net-core-3.1, iis-10

I have a controller method, which I can Post to (from Postman) when I run as localhost, but when deployed onto an IIS10 server, the Post fails.
i.e. The model sent is correct as is the url

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveLicence([FromBody] MXLockit_LicencingModel licenceResponse)
    {
```

Comment: `the Post fails`... Based on this information alone, I can guess that the possibility is that the application you deployed does not have sufficient permissions set. Please check that IIS_IUSRS or IUSR and `Full control` permissions are set in the corresponding directory. Otherwise, please provide more detailed information, such as a specific error message, error code/substatus code, minimal code example that reproduces the problem, or a screenshot of the error page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll convert my comment into an answer. If possible, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application works fine locally, but there are problems when deployed to IIS, first check whether its permissions are sufficient.

Check that `IIS_IUSRS` or `IUSR` and `Full control` permissions are set in the corresponding directory which app published in IIS.